# Redirect without showing default action index - Yii

Tags: php, yii, url-routing, yii-components, yii-url-manager

I want to know if is possible using `$this->redirect()` statement ,to redirect to a different controller but without showing the action , I mean, if i want to redirect to controller Person by default yii goes to `Person/index`, I want to redirect to `Person` (don't want to show the action Person == Person/index)

I know that with `$this->redirect()` I can use `$this->redirect(array(controller/action))`, but is always showing the index action.

Comment: What do you mean by showing the index action?

Comment: www.domain.com/controller/action , I want to redirect to www.domain.com/controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main.php, you should have these default rules in urlManager section:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Simply add this above the existing rules:

```
'<controller:\w+>/' => '<controller>/index',
```